# Assigning n players to 3-member teams to reduce number of repeated games?

Tags: algorithm

Sorry for the non-descriptive title. This is not a homework problem -- I have a friend who has asked me to help him assign teams for an FRC tournament he's running.

So I have *n* players and *x* games. Each game has two teams of three players. I'd like to generate a schedule that tries to minimize the number of repeated games (that is, I don't want two teams from playing each other twice, and all things being equal I'd rather that each team be as unique as possible (so players A, B, and C don't play on the same team the whole time)).

I'm not asking for a specific answer, but perhaps a pointer to what the formal name of the problem I'm trying to solve is?

*Edit:*

The priority should be placed on having as many unique (distinct) games as possible, while having each player play almost the same number of games (the difference between the player with the most games and the fewest games should be probably no greater than two, if that's possible).

This is not a round-robin *per se*, but if a round-robin-like tournament can solve this problem, I'd like to hear how. There is no limit on how many times a player will play another.

Players are interchangeable, so a team with players A, B, and C is equivalent to a team with players A, C, and B.

Comment: Team Players are interchangeable? How many rounds? Round-Robin tournament? Several constraints must be defined...

Comment: Can you provide some more information about what exactly it is you're trying to optimize over? If there aren't enough games for all combinations to play one another, what would you consider to be an "acceptable" schedule? Is it bad if one player plays way more games than other players?

Comment: @gtgaxiola I've updated the question to try to answer your questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general subject you are looking for is ["combinatorial design"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_design), which is a deep and complex branch of mathematics.

A complete mastery of combinatorial design would surely yield an easy solution to your scheduling problem.  However this would take several decades, and all the experts in the subject seem to be busy writing books.  All I could get out of it is that the number of possible games increases on the order of P!.

Fortunately a sub-branch, tournament scheduling, has benefited from the attention of some very practical and motivated people, and a number of general solutions are in common use.

Which of these deserves your attention depends on the size of your tournament parameters: the number of players, the number of simultaneous games per round, and the number of rounds you have time for.

My first idea was to use a modification of ["round-robin"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_tournament) scheduling.  If your tournament is beyond round-robin, it probably has other, more fatal, practical difficulties.

The difficulty with using round-robin for team composition is that players always end up on the same team with other players very near them on the player list.  So I modified my algorithm until the team composition, the game composition, and the leftover players who have to sit out a round (byes) were more evenly distributed.

The comments refer to differences from a straightforward round-robin, and that I noticed that my final effort has some steps in common with the "hailstone" PRNG.

```
parameter PLAYERCNT  // number of players

const TEAMCNT = 2  // number of teams in a game
const SLOTCNT = 3  // number of players on a team

const GAMECNT = trunc(PLAYERCNT / (TEAMCNT * SLOTCNT))  // max num simultaneous games

// the game and team assignment for one round
SEED : array [GAMECNT-1, TEAMCNT-1, SLOTCNT-1] of integer

POOL : array [PLAYERCNT-1] of boolean  // temp to mark selected players

// before generating any rounds:
  BASE = 0
  BUMP = 0
//

// to generate the next round:
  // make all players available for this round
  for PLAYER from 0 to PLAYERCNT-1 { POOL[PLAYER] = false }
  // changing the bump repeatedly breaks up the teams, otherwise players always
  // end up on the same team with someone within SLOTCNT on the player list
  BUMP = BUMP+1  // bump part of hailstone algo
  PLAYER = BASE
  // changing the base distributes the collisions evenly over the list
  // which also distributes the byes (players who have to sit out a round)
  BASE = (BASE + (TEAMCNT * SLOTCNT)) mod PLAYERCNT  // base part of hailstone algo
  // fill in the game and team assignments
  for GAME from 0 to GAMECNT-1 {
    for TEAM from 0 to TEAMCNT-1 {
      for SLOT from 0 to SLOTCNT-1 {
        SEED[GAME, TEAM, SLOT] = PLAYER
        POOL[PLAYER] = true  // mark player as no longer available
        // find next available player while detecting hailstone collisions
        while POOL[PLAYER] {
          PLAYER = (PLAYER + BUMP) mod PLAYERCNT
        }
        //
      }
    }
  }
//
```

Answer (score 1):

Combinatorial designs are encountered in test design, and you could try a modification of the approach described in http://testingeducation.org/BBST/testdesign/Cohen_AETG_System.pdf.

I assume that you want a schedule that consists of a series of rounds, where each round divides all the contestants up into pairs of triples (or perhaps groups of six). Your objective is then to maximize the number of distinct pairs of triples / groups of six occurring in the schedule. In fact if you have an objective slightly different from this the approach here will still work, as long as you can tell good schedules from bad schedules.

Generate the schedule round by round, keeping track of the set of triples/six-groups generated so far. For each round, produce some large number of random splits into triples/six-groups, and pick the random split found which produces most triples/six-groups not seen so far. Once you have chosen a best random split for a particular round, record it, update the set of triples/six-groups found so far, and move on to work out the next round.

Since this process is random, repeat the entire process with a different random seed to see if you get a better answer, and keep going until you run out of computer time.

In its original setting, the algorithm described there provides results which make all-pairs testing practical. They are not as good as those produced from known optimal combinatorial designs, but it is easy to program and very flexible.